# How to call three different functions to 1 main function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

The purpose of this program is to create three functions that call to a main function.

Here's the main function:

```
def main():

# initial roster
  brave_roster = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
        "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",
  }

  print("\t ***  Braves Stats!  ***\n")
  print("Welcome to My Braves Stats! What can I do for you?\n")
  print('  1. Search for a player')
  print('  2. Add a new player')
  print('  3. Remove a player')
  choice = int(input("Please type your choice number:"))
```

Here's Function one: This function looks up specific words in the dictionary.

```
def lookup_player(brave_roster, name, choice):
  
  player_look = input("Enter the name of the player you want to look up:")
  #while brave_roster == True:
  for name in brave_roster:
   if choice == 1:
      #print(brave_roster[name])
    print("Here are Austin's stats:", brave_roster[name])
   elif choice == 1:
      #print(player_look)
      print("Here are Ronald's stats:", brave_roster[name])
   else:
      choice == False
      print("N/A")
      
  return choice, name

  
def add_player_to_dict(brave_roster,new_player_add):
  

  playad = input("Enter the name of the player you want to add:")
  
  new_player_add = {}
  for i in range(1):
    player_name = input()
    player_stats = input()
    new_player_add[player_name] = player_stats

  while True:
    if choice == 2:
      print(playad,new_player_add)
      brave_roster.update(new_player_add)
    else: 
      choice == False
      print("That player already exists.")
      
      
    return new_player_add
```

Function Three removes keys from the dictionary:

```
def delete_in_dict(brave_roster):
  d_player = input("Enter the name of the player you want to remove:")
  x = input()

  while True:
    if choice == 3:
      print(d_player)
      for k in list(brave_roster.keys()):
        if brave_roster[k] == 1:
          del brave_roster[k]
    elif choice == 3:
      for k in list(brave_roster.keys()):
        if brave_roster[k] == 2:
          del brave_roster[k]
    else:
      print("Uh typo?", x, "Does not play for us:" )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice = main()
    brave_roster = {
        #"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
        #"Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",
    }
    player_look = lookup_player(brave_roster, name, choice)
    print("Thanks for using my Braves Stats.")
```

I've been trying multiple things to get these functions to work and I'm at a stand still.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the user of your program to choose which action to execute, and then after done it asks the user again to choose an action or exit.

Being that the case, this is how I suggest you to implement your pro:

```
"""this is the main function, it will call the chosen action"""
def main(brave_roster):
  # placing the selection inside a loop so the user can continue or leave
  while True:
    print("\nWhat can I do for you?")
    print("  1. Search for a player")
    print("  2. Add a new player")
    print("  3. Remove a player")

    choice = input("Please type your choice number:")
    # depending on the choice, call the corresponding function
    if (choice == "1"):
      lookup_player(brave_roster)
    elif (choice == "2"):
      add_player_to_dict(brave_roster)
    elif (choice == "3"):
      delete_in_dict(brave_roster)    
    else:
      # or else, press enter to exit
      break

"""lookup a player, otherwise fail if the name is not present"""
def lookup_player(brave_roster):
  name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to lookup:\n")
  # no need to hard code checking for each player
  # just check the the input name is in the dict
  if name in brave_roster:
    print("Here are the player's stats:", brave_roster[name])
  else:
    print("That player does not exist.")
  
"""add a player, otherwise fail if the name is already present"""
def add_player_to_dict(brave_roster):
  name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to add:\n")
  # only add if the name is not already there
  if name not in brave_roster:
    stats = input("Enter the player stats\n")
    # this is how you add a new item to the dict
    brave_roster[name] = stats
  else:
    print("That player already exists.")

"""delete a player, otherwise fail if the name is not present"""
def delete_in_dict(brave_roster):
  name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to remove:\n")
  if name in brave_roster:
    del brave_roster[name]
  else:
    print("\nThat player does not exist.")

# now, print the greeting, initialize the player database and
# call the main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("\t ***  Braves Stats!  ***\n")
  print("Welcome to My Braves Stats!")
  brave_roster = {
    "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
    "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",
  }
  main(brave_roster)
  print("\nThanks for using my Braves Stats.")
```